# iOS Application Submition Error on iPad application icon

Tags: codenameone

ERROR ITMS-90023: "Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '167x167' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions supporting iPad Pro."

Hi got the above message when try to submit built IPA file, using Mac's Application Loader..

Can anybody advice how to overcome this? I try to unzip that IPA file and found there is no 167x167 icon file for ipad. I try to create one and zip it back, but I got another error said "Invalid Signature" when try to resubmit using that "cheat" ipa file... should this 167x167 ipad icon file build by the codenameone build server as well?

Kindly advice.

Comment: Did you use standard xcode build or did you send a 9.2 build? Notice that 9.2 isn't ready for prime time so I suggest avoiding that. Also how did you upload the result? Don't use xcode you should use Application Loader on the binary

Comment: Yes, I use XCode 9.2. I will change to Default for the moment. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify the IPA after it's generated. This will break the signature. The icon also needs to be listed in a couple of places for it to work properly.

I've added this new 167px icon to the icon list so with the update tomorrow (Feb 9th 2018) it should "just work" for new builds.

Also notice that at this time only the standard build works properly for submission and we haven't yet tested the [new 9.2 builds](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/xcode-9-mode.html). It's also important you use Application Loader for upload and not xcode as that might break things.